# Issue when transitioning from "babel-preset-es2015" to "babel-preset-env" on React and Webpack project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a React project that had been using `babel-preset-es2015` that was getting built fine with webpack, but since I've moved to `babel-preset-env` the module build fails.

This error message appears:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/path/to/project"
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:175:20)
```

Below are my webpack configurations:

**WORKS (with babel-preset-2015)**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              'es2015',
              'react',
              'stage-1']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
};
```

**DOESN'T WORK (with babel-preset-env)**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              'env',
              'react',
              'stage-1']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
};
```

**package.json** dependencies:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0"
```

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and doing a fresh `npm install`?

Comment: Did you update your .babelrc file?

Comment: @Oblosys I have and it didn't help.

Comment: @Jaxx I didn't have a .babelrc.  Do I need to have one if I have the presets under 'options' in the webpack file?

Comment: No, it's ok to not have one if you use the options field, but if you had one and forgot to update it it might have caused interference, hence my question.

Comment: The odd thing is that, according to your error, some part of your app continues to reference the es2015 preset even though you switched to env. So the error is not really about the env-preset not working, it's more of an interference issue with an out-of-date piece of code. You can try what @Oblosys suggested. A full project search for "es2015" might also turn up something interesting.

Comment: @Jaxx adding the .babelrc file seems to have solve the issue.  I added details in the answer section.

Comment: I always use a .babelrc file in my projects, after running into similar issues as the one you had. But quite honestly, it's still a mystery to me why the options field in the babel-loader config does not produce exactly the same results as using a .babelrc file. This is probably particular to how Babel works, but still... Anyway, glad your issue is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

So I added a .babelrc file and moved the loader options there, and things appear to work just fine now.  Still not sure why it doesn't work inside the webpack module.

**Webpack**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ]
}
```